# R: changing the intervals between ticks in the axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, range, axis

I would like to change the distance between tick marks on the axis. At the moment the distance is always a constant value and I would like to change it the distance between ticks to the distance of: 100 untis, 100units, 50 units, 50 units, 900, 10, 100, 900 units. 
Is there any way of doing this?

My data looks essentially something like this:

```
    X1     A     B     C
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1  0.01  1000    10
2     2  0.02  2000    20
3     3  0.03  3000    30
4     4  0.04   100    10
5     5  1.30   100    10
6     6 10.20   100    10
```

My code for the plot so far:

```
st <- ggplot(stack(data), aes(x = factor(ind, levels = names(data)), y = values)) + 
      geom_boxplot()
```

I haven't found any indications or references of how to change the distance between the ticks and use different values for the different distances, therefore I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? What does your code look like? The more information you give the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice, I tried it but it didnt work, the axis is still the same.

Comment: Try: `ggplot(stack(data), aes(x = ind, y = values)) + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(100,200, 250,300,1200,1210,1310,2210))`

Comment: Whats about logging the y-axis using `scale_y_log10()`

Comment: it worked! Thank you!